# Issue getting OTP from message programatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

[image]I created an application consisting an OTP verification part. I'm able to fetch the message on receiving but I'm getting it as two parts as shown below while logging the message body -

- Sender Verification: Name: visakh r Pincode:12345. If the details are
  correct and you agree to the terms & conditions on www.abcdef.com Please acti
- vate your account using OTP 3136

My onReceive function is as

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdu_Objects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    if (pdu_Objects != null) {
                        prgDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        for (Object aObject : pdu_Objects) {

                            currentSMS = getIncomingMessage(aObject, bundle);

                            String senderNo = currentSMS.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                            message = currentSMS.getDisplayMessageBody();

                            String sndr = "SENDER";
                            if(senderNo.toLowerCase().contains(sndr.toLowerCase())) {
                                String CurrentString = message;
                                    try {
                                         String[] separated = CurrentString.split("OTP");

                                         ***otp2 = separated[1].trim().substring(2, 6);***

                                        if (otp2.matches("[0-9]+") && otp2.length() == 4) {

                                            otp_val.setText(otp2);
                                        } else {

                                            prgDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        Log.e("exception", "" + e);
                                    }

                            }
                        }
                        this.abortBroadcast();

                    }
                }
            }
        }


    private SmsMessage getIncomingMessage(Object aObject, Bundle bundle) {
        SmsMessage currentSMS;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            String format = bundle.getString("format");
            currentSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aObject, format);
        } else {
            currentSMS = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aObject);
        }

        return currentSMS;
    }
```

I am getting error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to use the substring **separated[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q6x7.png)** after splitting message body by string **OTP**.

result from log is attached as image.

Comment: String CurrentString = message; What is "CurrentString " ? Can you add the String in the comments below?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting whole 180 message in message ? Debug the code first .

Comment: The message body is given in the question. I logged the message and it shows the message in two parts as shown first in my question.

Comment: Added the image of log result.

Comment: The actual issue is the string "OTP" is in the message body ,but while splitting the message with respect to string "OTP"  substring at index 1 is getting null. What i have found while logging the results is that i'm getting the message as 2 parts as shown in the attached image. Please click on the image for better view.

Comment: Solved it. I found that the message i am getting is actually 2 messages. The OTP was in the second part. So i tested by removing the checking of starting string of the message , thus the second part of message,starting with some invalid string also got to loop for search for OTP and i got it correctly. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

you are try to get wrong substring use

```
String otp2 = separated[1].trim().substring(0, 4);
```

like below code

```
 try {
                                 String[] separated = CurrentString.split("OTP");

                                 String otp2 = separated[1].trim().substring(0, 4);

                                if (otp2.matches("[0-9]+") && otp2.length() == 4) {

                                    otp_val.setText(otp2);
                                } else {

                                    prgDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("exception", "" + e);
                            }
```

Comment: Not yet, Actually while splitting the mesage body with "OTP" i'm not getting 2 substrings. When i try to use the substring in index 1 it shows array out of bound exception

Comment: Solved it. I found that the message i am getting is actually 2 messages. The OTP was in the second part. So i tested by removing the checking of starting string of the message , thus the second part of message,starting with some invalid string also got to loop for search for OTP and i got it correctly. Thanks for your response @Omi